# Json_decode is not working

Tags: php, json, curl

I can see my json formatted response but once I try to decode and print specific value then it simply goes silent without printing error/null. tried almost all methods to access json.. Error reporting is on

```
$url = 'localhost:8080/app/api/Api.php?name=c';
$client = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($client, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$response = curl_exec($client);
$result = json_decode($response, true); // without true tried
echo $response; //prints json response
echo $result->count; // does not work here $result['count'] tried
```

`JSON` response as below:

```
{"status":200,"message":"data found","data":{"count":"1050"}}
```

Comment: is your error reporting enabled? Are you getting valid json string?

Comment: I have edited the post

Comment: @moomdid see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this to get individual values,

```
$url = 'localhost:8080/app/api/Api.php?name=c';
$client = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($client, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$response = curl_exec($client);
$result = json_decode($response, true);
echo $result['status'] . "<br />";  // 200
echo $result['message'] . "<br />"; // data found
echo $result['data']['count'] . "<br />";  // 1050
```

Output:

```
200
data found
1050
```

Answer (score 0):

In json_decode() you are telling the function to create an associative array instead of an object by setting the 2nd parameter to true. To make it an object just use:

```
$result = json_decode($response);
```

Otherwise, with your current methodology you can access the variable by using $result['count'];

Answer (score 0):

json_decode function has boolean when TRUE will returned objects will be converted into associative arrays. So if you would like to use objects instead of arrays remove TRUE

```
$url = 'localhost:8080/app/api/Api.php?name=c';
$client = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($client, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$response = curl_exec($client);
$result = json_decode($response);
echo $response; //prints json response
echo $result->count; // should work
```

or you can use arrays instead of objects

```
$url = 'localhost:8080/app/api/Api.php?name=c';
$client = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($client, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$response = curl_exec($client);
$result = json_decode($response, true);
echo $response; //prints json response
echo $result['count'];
```